# make buttonIcon icons bigger

Tags: lightning, lightning-design-system

How can I change the size of an icon inside of a lightning:buttonIcon ?

```
<div class="slds-grid slds-grid--vertical">       
        <div class="slds-col">
            <lightning:buttonIcon class="slds-size_medium" size="large" iconName="utility:fallback" alternativeText="nah"/>
     </div>
</div>
```

I am confused on how to properly style this. When the buttonIcon is inside a grid it doesn't seem to, rely on its own size attribute but by the size the grid assigns it. right ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is a standard solution for this.

You can do a little css hack:

define a unique class on you icon:

```
<lightning:buttonIcon iconName="utility:fallback" class="myUniqueClass" />
```

now add a css rule for the svg element that is inside your unique class:

```
.THIS .myUniqueClass svg {
    width: 3rem;
    height: 3rem;
}
```

I think that size 2rem is the default large icon, so play with the size yourself.

Be aware that any `svg` tag that will be inside an element with the `myUniqueClass` class will use that css rule!

Comment: looks good. lightning:buttonIcon has a 'iconClass' attribute. Does that do kinda the same thing ?

Comment: I am not really sure, you should try it

Answer (score 0):

change the class of the button icon

```
<lightning:buttonIcon iconClass="slds-size_large"... />
```

Comment: unfortunately that doesn't make the actual icon bigger